# How to connect JSON with a chartengine library

Tags: java, android, json, achartengine

I am using achartEngine to draw linechart in my android application. I am setting data in the code. Now I need to get data from JSON and display it in my graphics, but I don't know how to connect my JSON with achartengine and display it into linechart.

This is my wrong source code :

**parsing json**

```
public class ErizaChartEngine extends Activity {
List NabList = new ArrayList();
boolean statuskoneksi= true;
private ProgressDialog Dialog;
protected Context context;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    new LineChartAsyncTask().execute();
    setContentView(R.layout.layoutchart);

}
    public class LineChartAsyncTask extends AsyncTask <String, String, String>{

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute (){
            super.onPreExecute();
            Dialog=new ProgressDialog(ErizaChartEngine.this);
            Dialog.setMessage("Mohon Tunggu Sebentar...");
            Dialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            Dialog.setCancelable(true);
            Dialog.show();
        }


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String url= "http://www.ab.com/NabChart.htm?id=03&nilai=10";
            try {
                JSONParser jp= new JSONParser();
                JSONArray ja= jp.takeJson(url);

                for (int i=0; i<ja.length();i++){
                    JSONObject jo = ja.getJSONObject(i);
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    if (jo.has("lnu_nilai")) 
                        map.put("lnu_nilai", jo.get("lnu_nilai").toString());
                    if (jo.has("tanggal")) 
                        map.put("tanggal", jo.get("tanggal").toString());
                    NabList.add(map);
                    System.out.println("json parser done");
                }
            }
            catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            Dialog.dismiss();
}
```

This is my class for drawing graphics :

```
public void drawNABContentSimpleChart
    (
     String strtanggal,
     String strNilaiNABHMin0)
    {
        XYSeries nabseries = new XYSeries("nab");

        for (int i=0;i<NabList.size();i++){
            nabseries.add(strNilaiNABHMin0[i]);
        }
        XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
        // Adding Income Series to the dataset
        dataset.addSeries(nabseries);

        XYSeriesRenderer incomeRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        incomeRenderer.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        incomeRenderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
        incomeRenderer.setFillPoints(true);
        incomeRenderer.setLineWidth(2);
        incomeRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);

        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer multiRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
        multiRenderer.setXLabels(0);
        multiRenderer.setChartTitle("NAB 1 year");
        multiRenderer.setXTitle("Year 2012");
        multiRenderer.setYTitle("Nilai");
        multiRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);              
        for(int i=0;i<NabList.size();i++){
            multiRenderer.addXTextLabel(strtanggal[i]);         
        }       
        multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(incomeRenderer);
```

//          multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(expenseRenderer);

```
        // Creating an intent to plot line chart using dataset and multipleRenderer
        Intent intent = ChartFactory.getLineChartIntent(getBaseContext(), dataset, multiRenderer);

        // Start Activity
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

I really need help to solve my problem, because my  code still wrong and I don't know how to fix it. is there anyone can help me to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Just initialize the chart stuff (dataset, renderer) and start parsing your json. Add every data item you read from the file to your series in the dataset. Once you are done, display the chart.

Comment: can uou give me an example..? i don't understand what your mean, thank you